# RedirectToAction формируется не верно

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Проект asp.net core 2.0, в нём есть вот такой метод

```
public ActionResult InventNumberSearch (string inventNumber) {
    var asset = _context.Assets.FirstOrDefault (s => s.InventNumber == inventNumber);

    if (asset != null) {
        // return RedirectToAction ("Details", "Assets", new { id = asset.Id });
        return RedirectToAction ("Details", "Assets", new { @id = asset.Id });
        // return RedirectToAction (actionName: "Details", routeValues : new { id = asset.Id });
    } else {
        return RedirectToAction ("Index", "Offices");
    }    
}
```

который ищет товар и возвращает страницу Details, этого товара. Но ссылка формируется не правильно. Из за чего, товар находиться правильный, но картинка слетает.

Ссылка которая приходит получается такая:

```
http://localhost:60834/Assets/Details/8b176366-a057-4b9a-8386-dbe3926948a9
```

а, должна получиться такая:

```
http://localhost:60834/Assets/Details?id=8b176366-a057-4b9a-8386-dbe3926948a9
```

Не могу никак решить головоломку. Перепробовал несколько вариантов
которые за комментированы. Но не один не сработал. В чём может быть проблема.

Данные в метод передаю так:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("InventNumberSearch", "Assets", FormMethod.Post, new{
                                @role="search", @class="navbar-form-custom"}))
                                {
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        @Html.TextBox("InventNumber",null, new { @class="form-control",
                                        @placeholder="Поиск по инвентарному номеру...",
                                        @style="width: 250px;"})
                                        @Html.TextBox("InventNumberSearch","Поиск", new { @class="hidden",
                                        @type="submit"})
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                }
```

Route:

```
routes.MapRoute (
                    name: "default2",
                    template: "{controller=Offices}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: покажите настройки роутинга

Comment: @tym32167 добавил

Comment: Ну и? уберите /{id?} из роута (и будьте готовы, что поломается где-то ещё)

Comment: @A K как раз так сделал, работает! А, по чему должно поломаться где-то ещё?

Comment: Но ведь теперь по всему сайту ссылки будут через ?id= отображаться и может быть у вас есть места, где нужно как раз /id= Ведь у вас могут быть страницы типа /Order/Detail/123 а не /Order/Detail?id=123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите `/{id?}` из роута

```
routes.MapRoute (
                    name: "default2",
                    template: "{controller=Offices}/{action=Index}");
```

И будьте готовы, что поломается где-то ещё: ведь теперь по всему сайту ссылки будут через `?id=` отображаться и может быть у вас есть места, где нужно как раз `/id=`

Пример: страницы типа `/Order/Details/123` станут `/Order/Details?id=123`